# Speeding up videocomposing in pymovie

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm trying to resize videos similarly to what this api provides
https://creatomate.com/docs/json/quick-start/blur-video-background
I accomplished the result more or less but the problem is it takes ages to render out.
I'm a total beginner when it comes to video processing and for the life of me i can't figure out how to speed it up. When the rendering is running python only uses CPU at about 20% utilization.

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips,CompositeVideoClipimport datetimefrom skimage.filters import gaussian

def _blur(image):
  return gaussian(image.astype(float), sigma=25,preserve_range=True,channel_axis=-1)

def blurVideos(filenames):
  clips = [VideoFileClip(c) for c in filenames]
  overlay_clips = [VideoFileClip((c), has_mask=True) for c in filenames]
  overlay = concatenate_videoclips(overlay_clips,"chain")
  output = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="chain")
  print("Bluring video")
  blured_output = output.fl_image( _blur )
  print("Done")
  print("Resizing video")
  resized_output = blured_output.resize((1920,1080))
  print("Done")
  composited_output = CompositeVideoClip([resized_output.without_audio(),overlay.set_position("center","center")])
  composited_output.write_videofile(f"output/out_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.mp4",fps=20,threads=16,codec="h264_nvenc",preset="fast")
```

I've tried to use GPU accelerated codecs like h264_nvenc, I've tried to modify ffmpeg arguments under the hood of moviepy to use cuda also no succses
What can i do to speed this up?